# Databricks - Infer Schema Automatically or loop through rows to determine data type automatiicaly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm fetching JSON data from an online source. 
I'm able to retrieve the data just fine, but the only issue is that everything is defaulted to STRING data type. 
I want to ensure the data types are dynamically set such as Boolean, Datetime, Int, String etc.

If I use the method below, I get the following error

> ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "myJsonDataUrl"
try:
    dfPanda = pd.read_json(url)
    df = spark.createDataFrame(dfPanda)
except:
    dfPanda = pd.read_json(url, dtype='string')
    df = spark.createDataFrame(dfPanda)
```

I want to ensure the data types are dynamically set such as Boolean, Datetime, Int, String etc.

Comment: can you show data sample? Is it multiline object or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data types to be dynamically set as Boolean, Datetime, Int, or String better set Schema dynamically assign to the data frame.

And also as mentioned above the issue is with default  STRING using the Cast function to change different data types.

For the demo, I reproduce the same thing in my environment with a sample URL for the cast function.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1,name,href')
db1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([resp.text])
df2 = spark.read.json(db1)

df2.printSchema()
```

This is the Schema of sample Json rest API:
[image]

Now as per your schema. modify and use the cast function.

**Sample Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df_exp1 = df2.select(explode("data").alias("data"), "total", "total_pages")
df_cast12 = df_exp1.selectExpr(
    "CAST(data.id AS INT) AS id", 
    "CAST(data.first_name AS STRING) AS first_name", 
    "CAST(data.last_name AS STRING) AS last_name",
    "total",
    "total_pages"
)

display(df_cast12)
```

[image]

[image]